# Bootstrap 3.3.x as a Development Dependancy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I have a quick question. I just took over a React Boilerplate project. It uses  Material UI && Bootstrap. But bootstrap is only added as a development dependency. How will the boilerplate behave/work in production mode? I don't see how.

Package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^1.2.0-beta.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.1.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.3",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "csswring": "^5.1.0",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "expect": "^1.13.4",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-open-in-editor": "^1.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gapi": "0.0.3",
    "history": "^4.4.1",
    "http-proxy": "^1.12.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "postcss-import": "^9.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "qs": "^6.1.0",
    "rc-datepicker": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-calendar-component": "^1.0.0",
    "react-date-picker": "^5.3.28",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.37.0",
    "react-document-meta": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^5.1.0",
    "react-forms": "^2.0.0-beta33",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-loading-order-with-animation": "^1.0.0",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^5.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.3.0",
    "react-router": "3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.2.1",
    "redux-form": "^6.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "2.7.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "yargs": "^6.5.0"
  }
```

From bootstrap, we use mainly the grid and pull commands, for buttons. I don't get it though. Also, this is quite the complicated and old boilerplate.

Also another thing is that my scss doesn't get applied whatever method I use.. `Inline, scss, css`. I don't get it though. His webpack config is way too complicated, and I don't get it. Can someone help me.

Here is the webpack for Development:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'bootstrap-loader',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        './src/index',
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style!css?localIdentName=[path][name]--[local]!postcss-loader!sass',
        },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style!css?localIdentName=[path][name]--[local]!postcss-loader',
        }],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"development"',
            },
            __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        }),
    ],
};
```

The webpack for Production:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: ['bootstrap-loader/extractStyles'],

    output: {
        publicPath: 'dist/',
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style!css!postcss-loader!sass',
        }],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"',
            },
            __DEVELOPMENT__: false,
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

The common one:

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const development = require('./dev.config');
const production = require('./prod.config');

require('babel-polyfill').default;

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
};

process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;

const common = {
    entry: [
        PATHS.app,
    ],

    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js', '.json', '.scss', '.css'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', PATHS.app],
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//,
            loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery',
        }, {
            test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
        }, {
            test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2',
        }, {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream',
        }, {
            test: /\.otf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-otf',
        }, {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'file',
        }, {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml',
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }, {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
        }, {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
        }],
    },

    postcss: (webpack) => (
        [
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            }),
            postcssImport({
                addDependencyTo: webpack,
            }),
        ]
    ),
};

if (TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(development, common);
}

if (TARGET === 'build' || !TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(production, common);
}
```

If you could help me understand this. And also answer my question would be great thank you!!

Comment: If it has a link rel attribute the app could require the styles and the javascript from a CDN such as MaxCDN, instead of having it installed via npm or other package-manager. Have you checked the html code?

Comment: @Frix G: I'm aware of that - my comment wasn't a suggestion to make use of this approach, it was merely a hint on how bootstrap **can** be included without using a package manager/listing it in package.json (as stated on their [official website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) ). And **'I'm pretty sure..'** doesn't mean you have tested it - thats a vague guess on your side without any substantial proof..

Comment: defining as devDependencies or Dependencies does not mean that it is only going to be used during development, specially with webpack that pulls every single dependency that is being used in your application. I'll write more on it.

Comment: It doesn't have a link in HTML. The only thing I found was a . Bootstrap rc file. No idea what it does. Styles seems to be following some cash loader scoping I have no idea how to use.. Seems like I am gonna start a clean environment..thanks guys!!